# Page Redirection action tag

Tags: php, html

I am writing '#' in the action tag of a form and then including a php script to perform action on click of submit button.

HTML code:

```
<form id="newsletter" method="post" action="#">
          <div class="input-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="news">Full Name</label>
            <input type="email" id="news" name="news" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit">Subscribe</button>
            </span> </div>
        </form>
        <?php include "newsletter.php"?>
```

I want the index page to be redirected to a different page once the work is done. header[Location] doesnt seem to work as as it is giving an error of header already sent.

php code:

```
<?php

    if($_POST){


        $email = $_POST["news"];
        $subject = "New Subscribe for Newsletter";
        $message = "<b>From : ".$email."</b><br/>";
        $message = "<b>Subscriber from mailnews: $email</b>";
        $from = "contact@email.com";
        $to = "mailnews@email.com";

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $headers .= 'To: MailNews<'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Contacted from <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);




?>

    <?php }


?>
```

Comment: where is your php codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: php code added as requested

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of your php include the function

```
  <?php

    Ob_start();

  ?>
```

Now you shouldn't get header already sent error. Make sure it's the first thing after your opening php tag.